yarn installs old version of local package
I have a local package example-0.0.0.tgz and I installed with command yarn add ./local-packages/example-0.0.0.tgz.
Then I uninstalled example package, deleted yarn cache and node-modules. Then I made some changes and created same package with same version example-0.0.0.tgz locally. Then I ran same command to install the package yarn add ./local-packages/example-0.0.0.tgz.
Some even after clean install, my new changes are not available. When I open the components inside the example-0.0.0.tgz I can see my changes but when I look into the components from node-modules/example, new changes are not available.
Somehow yarn keep installing the first version of the example package. How can I force yarn to install the package so that new changes are include?
